# send grid mail in async way

Tags: javascript, sendgrid

```js
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');

const {
  keys,
} = require('../../config/config');

async function forgotPassword(req, res) {
  
  try {
    //...
    sgMail.setApiKey(keys.sendGridKey);
    const msg = {
      to: `${req.body.email}`,
      from: 'no-reply@example.com',
      subject: 'Forgot password request',
      text: 'You get this email because of you asked to reset password',
      html: `<strong>${token}</strong>`,
    };
    sgMail.send(msg);
   
    res.sendStatus(200);
  } catch (error) {
   
    res.status(500).json(error.message);
  }
}
```

I have this code snippet in my nodejs project. Which is working correctly. But the only problem is this isn't work in async manner. I try to find that in the official docs and I couldn't find that in there. Putting `await` in the `send` function, is that all I need to do to make this work as an async function.

```
await sgMail.send(msg);
```

Comment: Are you concerned about response here ? Do you really need to check response ?  if not then let it be fire and forget.

Comment: `this isn't work in async manner` what do you mean? Why have you made the function `async` if you are never using `await`?

Comment: perhaps if you [read some documentation](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/blob/master/use-cases/success-failure-errors.md) and use the Promises that `.send` returns, you'd get asynchrony :p ... quick fix ... `await sgMail.send(msg);` ... done

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They added example to send async in [GitHub](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/tree/main/packages/mail)

Here is the code:

```
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
const msg = {
  to: 'test@example.com',
  from: 'test@example.com', // Use the email address or domain you verified above
  subject: 'Sending with Twilio SendGrid is Fun',
  text: 'and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js',
  html: '<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js</strong>',
};
//ES6 Old way
sgMail
  .send(msg)
  .then(() => {}, error => {
    console.error(error);

    if (error.response) {
      console.error(error.response.body)
    }
  });
//ES8 - Async example
(async () => {
  try {
    await sgMail.send(msg);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);

    if (error.response) {
      console.error(error.response.body)
    }
  }
})();
```